# How a comment becomes an answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

It was brought up in a comment-block under a recent question that the practice of deleting comments that are (or have the potential of becoming) actual answers is potentially troubling to commenters.

Is there a consistent and defensible rubric concerning how *close* a comment is to being an answer that causes it to be removed? Is/should there be a waiting period before deletion?

[Note: I don't care much one way or the other. To me it was the mildest of inconveniences to have a comment deleted, but it sounded like maybe there was more to say on the matter.]

Comment: I didn't remember this previous discussion, but here is a related thread: https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/651/posting-mini-answers-in-comments

Comment: My preference is that if you think a comment should be an answer, just write one up.  Don't fuss at the original writer to do so.  Don't erase the comment.  But of course give acknowledgment, cite the comment.

Comment: P.s.  And it's pretty annoying to be told to make a comment and answer, doing so, and then have it get slagged for being too short or the like.  In that case, really, just write it up yourself (if it bugs you to see answers in comment, doesn't really bug me).